# How Do I Access Profile Info From Relying Party?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-membership, profile, thinktecture-ident-server

I have Thinktecture Identity Server 2 running locally for development purposes and have set up Microsoft Membership as its User storage.  I'm using SqlRoleProvider and something called SqlTableProfileProvider and that's all working fine and dandy.

My questions are, what is the best way to access the profile information from within the Relying Party web site (ASP.Net Web Forms) so I can display that profile information to the user?  Do I need to configure my web.config with the ProfileProvider information that is also in Identity Server's configs?  How do I then programmatically access that profile data from my code behind (C#)?

Any insights would be welcome.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't. The profile provider in IdSrv is used to add claims to the outgoing token.

If you really want to access the profile from the RP you would need to add a web service endpoint to IdSrv that exposes it.